# robocopy copy files to folders already in destination

Tags: robocopy

been trying to wrap my head around this one for a while.

I have a folder containing homefolders for my users.
ex:

username1
username2
username3
username4

Now i want to copy username2 and username 4 to %destination%

Would it work creating the folders on the destination and make robocopy only copy those 2 folders over?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for each folder

```
robocopy username2 destination_folder\username2 /copyall /e
```